# Not Getting any Record from View in Sql from MSCRM Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm

I am accessing MSCRM Databse.I am not getting any record from View in SQL.I get  all the record from table  but not getting any Record from View.If i login to server and then select the view then it shows me all data but if i am accessing the database from another machine then it doesnt show me any Record.Its not gives me any erroor but simply not getting any record from View..

Comment: Same Problem i am Facing before not getting any answer ...

Comment: do you know is there any permission Required for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user needs to be defined as a user within the CRM application itself, with permission to read the entity type you are querying. The SQL views for CRM take into account the currently logged on user and ultimately JOIN to the systemuser (aka the user record in CRM).

Record visibility is driven by CRM role and, depending on your access level, the underlying owner of the record. For example if you can only see "contacts" at "business unit" level and a colleague in a different business unit owns "Contact A", you will not see "Contact A".

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the database using some other user account. May be your user account not having any data access permissions.